# How can I implement custom GRU in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am trying to implement a custom GRU layer in keras 2.1.2-py36_0 where i want to use the following gate equations:

z<sub>t</sub> = act ( W<sub>z</sub>.h<sub>t-1</sub> + x<sub>t</sub> )
r<sub>t</sub> = act ( W<sub>r</sub>.h<sub>t-1</sub> + x<sub>t</sub> )
h<sub>t</sub> = act ( W<sub>h</sub>.(r * h<sub>t-1</sub>) + x<sub>t</sub> )

instead of keras current implementation of gates as:

z<sub>t</sub> = act ( W<sub>z</sub>.h<sub>t-1</sub> + U<sub>z</sub>x<sub>t</sub> )
r<sub>t</sub> = act ( W<sub>r</sub>.h<sub>t-1</sub> + U<sub>r</sub>x<sub>t</sub> )
h<sub>t</sub> = act ( W<sub>h</sub>.(r * h<sub>t-1</sub>) + U<sub>h</sub>x<sub>t</sub> )

Customizing GRU cell for the data

class CGRUCell(Layer):

```
def __init__(self, units,
             activation='tanh',
             recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
             use_bias=True,
             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
             recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
             bias_initializer='zeros',
             kernel_regularizer=None,
             recurrent_regularizer=None,
             bias_regularizer=None,
             kernel_constraint=None,
             recurrent_constraint=None,
             bias_constraint=None,
             dropout=0.,
             recurrent_dropout=0.,
             implementation=1,
             **kwargs):
    super(CGRUCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.units = units
    self.activation = activations.get(activation)
    self.recurrent_activation = activations.get(recurrent_activation)
    self.use_bias = use_bias

    self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
    self.recurrent_initializer = initializers.get(recurrent_initializer)
    self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)

    self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
    self.recurrent_regularizer = regularizers.get(recurrent_regularizer)
    self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)

    self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
    self.recurrent_constraint = constraints.get(recurrent_constraint)
    self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)

    self.dropout = min(1., max(0., dropout))
    self.recurrent_dropout = min(1., max(0., recurrent_dropout))
    self.implementation = implementation
    self.state_size = self.units
    self._dropout_mask = None
    self._recurrent_dropout_mask = None

def build(self, input_shape):
    input_dim = input_shape[-1]
    #self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units * 3),
    #                              name='kernel',
    #                              initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
    #                              regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
    #                              constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
    self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
        shape=(self.units, self.units * 3),
        name='recurrent_kernel',
        initializer=self.recurrent_initializer,
        regularizer=self.recurrent_regularizer,
        constraint=self.recurrent_constraint)

    if self.use_bias:
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units * 3,),
                                    name='bias',
                                    initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                    regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                    constraint=self.bias_constraint)
    else:
        self.bias = None

    #self.kernel_z = self.kernel[:, :self.units]
    self.recurrent_kernel_z = self.recurrent_kernel[:, :self.units]
    #self.kernel_r = self.kernel[:, self.units: self.units * 2]
    self.recurrent_kernel_r = self.recurrent_kernel[:,
                                                    self.units:
                                                    self.units * 2]
    #self.kernel_h = self.kernel[:, self.units * 2:]
    self.recurrent_kernel_h = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 2:]

    if self.use_bias:
        self.bias_z = self.bias[:self.units]
        self.bias_r = self.bias[self.units: self.units * 2]
        self.bias_h = self.bias[self.units * 2:]
    else:
        self.bias_z = None
        self.bias_r = None
        self.bias_h = None
    self.built = True

def call(self, inputs, states, training=None):
    h_tm1 = states[0]  # previous memory

    if 0 < self.dropout < 1 and self._dropout_mask is None:
        self._dropout_mask = _generate_dropout_mask(
            _generate_dropout_ones(inputs, K.shape(inputs)[-1]),
            self.dropout,
            training=training,
            count=3)
    if (0 < self.recurrent_dropout < 1 and
            self._recurrent_dropout_mask is None):
        self._recurrent_dropout_mask = _generate_dropout_mask(
            _generate_dropout_ones(inputs, self.units),
            self.recurrent_dropout,
            training=training,
            count=3)

    # dropout matrices for input units
    dp_mask = self._dropout_mask
    # dropout matrices for recurrent units
    rec_dp_mask = self._recurrent_dropout_mask

    if self.implementation == 1:
        if 0. < self.dropout < 1.:
            inputs_z = inputs * dp_mask[0]
            inputs_r = inputs * dp_mask[1]
            inputs_h = inputs * dp_mask[2]
        else:
            inputs_z = inputs
            inputs_r = inputs
            inputs_h = inputs
        print(inputs)    
        # Custom implementation of inputs which are already embedding parameters
        #x_z = K.dot(inputs_z, self.kernel_z)
        #x_r = K.dot(inputs_r, self.kernel_r)
        #x_h = K.dot(inputs_h, self.kernel_h)
        #if self.use_bias:
        #    x_z = K.bias_add(x_z, self.bias_z)
        #    x_r = K.bias_add(x_r, self.bias_r)
        #    x_h = K.bias_add(x_h, self.bias_h)
        x_z = inputs_z
        x_r = inputs_r
        x_h = inputs_h

        if 0. < self.recurrent_dropout < 1.:
            h_tm1_z = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[0]
            h_tm1_r = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[1]
            h_tm1_h = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[2]
        else:
            h_tm1_z = h_tm1
            h_tm1_r = h_tm1
            h_tm1_h = h_tm1
        z = self.recurrent_activation(x_z + K.dot(h_tm1_z,
                                                  self.recurrent_kernel_z))
        r = self.recurrent_activation(x_r + K.dot(h_tm1_r,
                                                  self.recurrent_kernel_r))

        hh = self.activation(x_h + K.dot(r * h_tm1_h,
                                         self.recurrent_kernel_h))
    else:
        if 0. < self.dropout < 1.:
            inputs *= dp_mask[0]

        # Custom implementation of inputs which are already embedding parameters
        #matrix_x = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
        #if self.use_bias:
        #    matrix_x = K.bias_add(matrix_x, self.bias)
        matrix_x = inputs

        if 0. < self.recurrent_dropout < 1.:
            h_tm1 *= rec_dp_mask[0]
        matrix_inner = K.dot(h_tm1,
                             self.recurrent_kernel[:, :2 * self.units])

        x_z = matrix_x[:, :self.units]
        x_r = matrix_x[:, self.units: 2 * self.units]
        recurrent_z = matrix_inner[:, :self.units]
        recurrent_r = matrix_inner[:, self.units: 2 * self.units]

        z = self.recurrent_activation(x_z + recurrent_z)
        r = self.recurrent_activation(x_r + recurrent_r)

        x_h = matrix_x[:, 2 * self.units:]
        recurrent_h = K.dot(r * h_tm1,
                            self.recurrent_kernel[:, 2 * self.units:])
        hh = self.activation(x_h + recurrent_h)
    h = z * h_tm1 + (1 - z) * hh
    if 0 < self.dropout + self.recurrent_dropout:
        if training is None:
            h._uses_learning_phase = True
    return h, [h]

def get_config(self):
    config = {'units': self.units,
              'activation': activations.serialize(self.activation),
              'recurrent_activation': activations.serialize(self.recurrent_activation),
              'use_bias': self.use_bias,
              'kernel_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.kernel_initializer),
              'recurrent_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.recurrent_initializer),
              'bias_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.bias_initializer),
              'kernel_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.kernel_regularizer),
              'recurrent_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.recurrent_regularizer),
              'bias_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.bias_regularizer),
              'kernel_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.kernel_constraint),
              'recurrent_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.recurrent_constraint),
              'bias_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.bias_constraint),
              'dropout': self.dropout,
              'recurrent_dropout': self.recurrent_dropout,
              'implementation': self.implementation}
    base_config = super(CGRUCell, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

class CGRU(RNN):

```
@interfaces.legacy_recurrent_support
def __init__(self, units,
             activation='tanh',
             recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
             use_bias=True,
             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
             recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
             bias_initializer='zeros',
             kernel_regularizer=None,
             recurrent_regularizer=None,
             bias_regularizer=None,
             activity_regularizer=None,
             kernel_constraint=None,
             recurrent_constraint=None,
             bias_constraint=None,
             dropout=0.,
             recurrent_dropout=0.,
             implementation=1,
             return_sequences=False,
             return_state=False,
             go_backwards=False,
             stateful=False,
             unroll=False,
             **kwargs):
    if implementation == 0:
        warnings.warn('`implementation=0` has been deprecated, '
                      'and now defaults to `implementation=1`.'
                      'Please update your layer call.')

    cell = CGRUCell(units,
                   activation=activation,
                   recurrent_activation=recurrent_activation,
                   use_bias=use_bias,
                   kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                   recurrent_initializer=recurrent_initializer,
                   bias_initializer=bias_initializer,
                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
                   recurrent_regularizer=recurrent_regularizer,
                   bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer,
                   kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
                   recurrent_constraint=recurrent_constraint,
                   bias_constraint=bias_constraint,
                   dropout=dropout,
                   recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout,
                   implementation=implementation)
    super(CGRU, self).__init__(cell,
                              return_sequences=return_sequences,
                              return_state=return_state,
                              go_backwards=go_backwards,
                              stateful=stateful,
                              unroll=unroll,
                              **kwargs)
    self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)

def call(self, inputs, mask=None, training=None, initial_state=None):
    self.cell._dropout_mask = None
    self.cell._recurrent_dropout_mask = None
    return super(CGRU, self).call(inputs,
                                 mask=mask,
                                 training=training,
                                 initial_state=initial_state)

@property
def units(self):
    return self.cell.units

@property
def activation(self):
    return self.cell.activation

@property
def recurrent_activation(self):
    return self.cell.recurrent_activation

@property
def use_bias(self):
    return self.cell.use_bias

@property
def kernel_initializer(self):
    return self.cell.kernel_initializer

@property
def recurrent_initializer(self):
    return self.cell.recurrent_initializer

@property
def bias_initializer(self):
    return self.cell.bias_initializer

@property
def kernel_regularizer(self):
    return self.cell.kernel_regularizer

@property
def recurrent_regularizer(self):
    return self.cell.recurrent_regularizer

@property
def bias_regularizer(self):
    return self.cell.bias_regularizer

@property
def kernel_constraint(self):
    return self.cell.kernel_constraint

@property
def recurrent_constraint(self):
    return self.cell.recurrent_constraint

@property
def bias_constraint(self):
    return self.cell.bias_constraint

@property
def dropout(self):
    return self.cell.dropout

@property
def recurrent_dropout(self):
    return self.cell.recurrent_dropout

@property
def implementation(self):
    return self.cell.implementation

def get_config(self):
    config = {'units': self.units,
              'activation': activations.serialize(self.activation),
              'recurrent_activation': activations.serialize(self.recurrent_activation),
              'use_bias': self.use_bias,
              'kernel_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.kernel_initializer),
              'recurrent_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.recurrent_initializer),
              'bias_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.bias_initializer),
              'kernel_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.kernel_regularizer),
              'recurrent_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.recurrent_regularizer),
              'bias_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.bias_regularizer),
              'activity_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.activity_regularizer),
              'kernel_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.kernel_constraint),
              'recurrent_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.recurrent_constraint),
              'bias_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.bias_constraint),
              'dropout': self.dropout,
              'recurrent_dropout': self.recurrent_dropout,
              'implementation': self.implementation}
    base_config = super(CGRU, self).get_config()
    del base_config['cell']
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

@classmethod
def from_config(cls, config):
    if 'implementation' in config and config['implementation'] == 0:
        config['implementation'] = 1
    return cls(**config)
```

Model Implementation is as follows:

```
    user_input = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size,chunk_size,), dtype='int32', name='user_inputs')
    user_emb = Embedding(input_dim=num_users+1, output_dim=out_dim, input_length=chunk_size)(user_input)
    item_input = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size,chunk_size,), dtype='int32', name='item_inputs')
    item_emb = Embedding(input_dim=num_items+1, output_dim=out_dim, input_length=chunk_size)(item_input)
    inputs = keras.layers.add([user_emb, item_emb])

    gru_args = {
        "units":hidden_size,
        "return_sequences":True,
        #"return_state":True,
        "stateful":True,
        "unroll":False
    }
    gru = CGRU(**gru_args)(inputs)
    outputs = Dense(num_items+1, activation='softmax')(gru)

    [recc_model = Model(inputs=\[user_input,item_input\], outputs=outputs)
    recc_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=\[metrics.cate][1]gorical_accuracy])
              #metrics=[metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy])
```

But on running the code I am getting the following error which seems is due to gradients are getting computed to None:

```
ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

Find the complete error here: https://pastebin.com/n9UzCRiP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the bias weights are added to the model but not used anywhere.

When you call `self.add_weight(...)`, you have to make sure these weights are used somewhere in your model. Otherwise, since these weights are not connected to the loss tensor, TF cannot compute the gradient and an error will be raised.

If you don't need the bias weights, you can either remove the `add_weight` lines, or set `use_bias=False` in your cell.

Also, I think you don't need to re-implement a `CGRU` layer to use a custom cell. Just wrap your custom cell with the built-in `RNN` layer should work.

```
gru = RNN(CGRUCell(hidden_size, use_bias=False),
          return_sequences=True,
          stateful=True,
          unroll=False)(inputs)
```

Comment: Thank you @Yu-Yang it fixed my issue, I overlooked bias weights and thanks for the tip.